# Download file's with date in file name from azure blob irrespective of the name before the date

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

i am running this script download file's with date in file name, but no output or error.

```
$container_name = 'xxxxx'
$destination_path = 'xyxyxyx'
$DateRef = (Get-Date)
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext $vcvcv -StorageAccountKey $cdkhcks=
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name  | Where {
    $_.BaseName -match '\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}' -and [datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}').Value),'yyyy_MM_dd',$null) -le $DateRef } |
  Foreach-Object {
            Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name  -Destination $destination_path
        }
```

Could someone help me in this. I need the script which should search the date in the filename and matches with current date and download it. For example if i have qwe_24122021,ert_24122021, it has to download both the file.

Comment: Your regex `'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}'` won't work on files like `qwe_24122021` because obviously the date format in those names is `'ddMMyyyy'`. Try with `'_(\d{8})$'`. Also do `$DateRef = (Get-Date).Date` so you won't match against the **current** time of day, but match the date to midnight

Comment: **i tried with this, but the data is not downloaded to the destination** it just run and no output.
'$Listblob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name  | Where {
    $_.BaseName -match '_(\d{8})$' -and [datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'_(\d{8})$').Value),'yyyy_MM_dd',$null) -le $DateRef } |
Foreach-Object {
Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name -Blob $Listblob -Destination $destination_path
}' @Theo

Comment: The format you use for ParseExact ('yyyy_MM_dd') is still wrong. Should be  `'ddMMyyyy'`. Also, do these files have an extension or not?. Not only that, but you forget to tell `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` what file it should download.. Add `-Blob $_.Name`

Comment: @Theo **Ya these files have .txt extension. Made the suggested changes,but no output.** '$Listblob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name  | Where {
    $_.BaseName -match '_(\d{8})$' -and [datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'_(\d{8})$').Value),'ddMMyyyy','$Null') -le $DateRef } |
Foreach-Object {
Get-AzStorageBlobcontent -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name -Blob $_.Name -Destination $destination_path
}'

Comment: [1] Then why didn't you post that in your question??? Now, the regex should be `'_(\d{8})\.txt$'`. [2] Remove `$Listblob =` and in the ForEach-Object loop use `-Blob $_.Name` [3] I'm not at all sure if your line `$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext ...` will actualy return a valid Context.. The syntax there is incorrect. Please read the examples for [New-AzStorageContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-7.0.0) carefully.

Comment: **I have used the same syntax previously, it is working. made all the suggested changes,but no output.** '$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext ee -StorageAccountKey vv
Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name  | Where {
    $_.BaseName -match '_(\d{8})\.txt$' -and [datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'_(\d{8})\.txt$').Value),'ddMMyyyy','$Null') -le $DateRef } |
Foreach-Object {
 Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name -Blob $_.Name  -Destination $destination_path }'@Theo

Comment: Sorry, `'_(\d{8})\.txt$'` was wrong since you are matching the BaseName, not the full Name. Please try my answer

Comment: @Theo **Actually, the suggested code is running, but no output. No data is downloading and no error. it runs & come back to the starting point**

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments, there are some mistakes in your code:

- if filenames have format `qwe_24122021.txt` etc. then the date part in nthese files have format `ddMMyyyy`
- To get a datetime out of this name, you need to use `$_.BaseName,'(\d{8})$').Value`, **not** `$_.BaseName,'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}'` because that doesn't look like the format used at all..
- I don't think you are getting a correct Context object with your code

I can't test this myself, but try:

```
$null = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$container_name   = 'xxxxx'
$destination_path = 'xyxyxyx'
$DateRef          = (Get-Date).Date
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'YOUR ACCOUNT NAME HERE' -StorageAccountKey 'YOUR KEY HERE'

Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name | 
    Where-Object { 
        $_.BaseName -match '_(\d{8})$' -and 
        [datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'(\d{8})$').Value),'ddMMyyyy',$null) -eq $DateRef 
    } |
    Foreach-Object {
        Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $_.Name -Destination $destination_path
    }
```

Comment: **Actually, the code is running, but no output. No data is downloading and no error. it runs & come back to the starting point.** @theo

Comment: i have these files inside the blob ""app_24122021.txt, ton_24122021.txt,nze24122021.txt"" @theo

Comment: when i removed for loop Get-AzStorageBlobContent : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Blob' because it is null.

Comment: @gopi Sorry, I'm out.. This is taking way too long..  Check the code piece by piece. [1] See if $Ctx is valid or $null [2] See what `Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name` returns (if anything) . Are these FileInfo objects? [3] See what it returns after the `Where-Object` clause (if anything) etc.

Comment: No issues @theo, anyway Thanks a lot for the help.